# Is it possible to embed tailwind classes in a Svelte custom component isolated inside the Shadow DOM?

Tags: tailwind-css, svelte, web-component

I am building a custom component (web component) in Svelte and Tailwind.

My goal is to make this component have self-contained styling, but I have trouble with including the Tailwind stylesheet inside my custom component as it is isolated inside a Shadow DOM.

MyComponent.svelte

```html
<svelte:options
  customElement={{
    tag: "my-component",
  }}
/>

<script>
  import Child from "./Child.svelte";
</script>

<span class="text-blue-500 p-4">
  Foo
  <Child />
</span>
```

Child.svelte

```html
<span class="p-4 text-red-500">Bar</span>
```

When using `<my-component></my-component>`, it is unstyled, as the component is inside the ShadowDOM, it does not have access to the global Tailwind stylesheet.

Is there a way to embed the full Tailwind stylesheet for my component inside the Shadow DOM?

I have had some success with using the svelte preprocessor

svelte.config.js

```js
export default {
  preprocess: [preprocess(), vitePreprocess()],
};
```

and including a link to my tailwind stylesheet in my component

```html
<style lang="postcss" src="./../app.css"></style>
```

but this is quite cumbersome, as I need to add this line for EVERY child component of MyComponent.svelte

Comment: its OOP. In native JS Web Components you just define one single BaseClass and extend your other components from that. Can't you do that in Svelte?

Comment: @Danny'365CSI'Engelman: You can't, and in most scenarios it would not even make sense anyway.

Comment: If you can avoid it, I would recommend just not using web components, they have a non-negligible number of limitations.

Comment: Yeah, I never teach my students Map and Set either, Arrays are just fine.  PS. every ``<input> <video> <textarea>`` and the like **_is_** built with (user-agent) Web Component technology

Comment: You might want to check out tailwind's `@apply`, for details see my other answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75034733/3617380).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution we opted for, was to add a script that imports the css into the Web Components. Inside the html document, we added a `<template>`:

```html
    <my-component></my-component>
    <template id="my-compontent-styling">
      <style>
        @import url("/assets/app.css")
      </style>
    </template>
```

And then in MyComponent.svelte, we inject the css

```html
<svelte:options
  customElement={{
    tag: "my-component",
  }}
/>

<script>
  import Child from "./Child.svelte";

  function applyStyling(divElement) {
    if (!divElement) return;
    const template = document.getElementById("my-component-styling");
    const node = document.importNode(template.content, true);
    divElement.parentNode.appendChild(node);
  }

  let divElement;
  $: applyStyling(divElement);
</script>

<div bind:this={divElement}>
  <span class="text-blue-500 p-4">
    Foo
    <Child />
  </span>
</div>
```

Comment: When having many components, the logic of `applyStyling` and `<div bind:this={divElement}>` could possibly be separated into its own component, eg.
`<ApplyCss>`

Answer (score 3):

As other members said in the comments, there is no clean answer to this. The entire purpose of Shadow DOM is to encapsulate the internal parts of the components from external environment.

Having said that, there is something you can do with new [`adoptedStyleSheets`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ShadowRoot/adoptedStyleSheets) property available on [`ShadowRoot`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ShadowRoot). Just like we have DOM for manipulating HTML Tree using JavaScript API, we also have, for the lack of better word, the COM (CSS Object Model) API that allow you to manipulate CSS using JavaScript APIs.

The recent addition to these APIs is the `adoptedStyleSheets` and [`constructed stylesheet`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSSStyleSheet/CSSStyleSheet). The idea is very simple:

- Construct a stylesheet dynamically using `CSSStyleSheet` contructor.
- Add CSS/Style rules to this style sheet.
- Attach this style sheet to one or more Shadow Roots.

```js
// Step 1: Construct a stylesheet:
const mySheet = new CSSStyleSheet();

// Step 2: Add the stylesheet rules:
// Specifically, add the Tailwind styles and rules
mySheet.replaceSync('h1 { padding: 2rem }');

// Apply the stylesheet to a document:
document.adoptedStyleSheets = [mySheet];

// Apply the stylesheet to a Shadow Root:
const node = document.createElement('my-component');

// Mode can be `closed` or `open`.
// Of course, doing this for `open` mode doesn't make sense.
const shadow = node.attachShadow({ mode: 'closed' });
shadow.adoptedStyleSheets = [mySheet];
```

In order to attach this to the top level `document` object, you can simply do:

```js
// Combine existing sheets with our new one:
document.adoptedStyleSheets = [...document.adoptedStyleSheets, mySheet];
```

This should solve your problem and make the global styles available inside all the shadow roots that you want. **But now, where is the catch?**

#### Getting Tailwind along

There are two key things to note with Tailwind. First, it is not a design system where you just get a pre-compiled CSS file that you can simply reference in you project. There is no CSS file. In fact, it is more like a compiler that generates a CSS code during compilation of your project.

Second, it is a utility-first framework for styling (note, styling not CSS. It just happens to use the same syntax as that of CSS.). So, it is expected that this will be available globally across your HTML tree, components (if you are using framework). Now, it goes exactly against the idea of ShadowDOM which is all about encapsulation.

So, in order to use the Tailwind, first you will have to generate it separately from your compiler/bundler (Vite.js or Svelte in your case). This means you may not be able to leverage the DX provided by the framework integration.

#### Cumbersome

The Tailwind will generate a standalone CSS file. If you are using a bundler like Webpack, then it is easy. You will probably use `svelte-loader` and  `raw-loader` for importing CSS as a plain string such that you can create a constructed stylesheet:

```js
// Ensure that raw-loader or equivalent is configured.
import tailWindCssAsString from '../tailwind.css';

const mySheet = new CSSStyleSheet();
mySheet.replaceSync(tailWindCssAsString);

// ... use the `mySheet` with `adoptedStyleSheets`
```

Alternately, if you do not something like this, then you may need to use CSS `@import` At-rule to point to the CSS like:

```js
const mySheet = new CSSStyleSheet();

// Ensure to use correct URL path for loading CSS when app is deployed to the server.
mySheet.replaceSync(`
  @import url("/tailwind.css");
`);
```

This definitely adds an initial delay with extra network request which will result in [FOUC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flash_of_unstyled_content).

#### Applying the stylesheet

Finally, if nothing else, you will also have to think about when and where to apply the **constructed stylesheet**. Ideally, you would like to ensure that the styles are applied to all the instances of the components and since, you are using web components, the best place to do this is constructor as shown in [this article](https://medium.com/webf/on-styling-web-components-b74b8c70c492).

Since, I have not used Svelte before, I don't know if it provides constructor equivalent lifecycle method or not. I guess it would probably be `onMount` method which will work but not exactly as good as constructor.

And, a last point, you will have to do this for every single component whose `mode` is `closed`.

---

For more information, read [this](https://web.dev/constructable-stylesheets/) and [that](https://github.com/WICG/construct-stylesheets/blob/gh-pages/explainer.md)!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can create a top component like this:

```
<svelte:options customElement="cust-element" />

<script lang="ts">
    import TestComponent from "./TestComponent.svelte";
    import libstyles from "./app.css?inline"

    let style = '<style>' + libstyles + '</style>'
</script>

{@html style}
<TestComponent></TestComponent>
```